# WPF Binding - Disabling a GroupBox when a CheckBox is Checked

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I'm new to WPF Binding and trying to disable a GroupBox called "GrpRecurEndDate" when a CheckBox "RunOnce" is checked. I tried following the post below but not having much luck getting the binding working. Any help would be appreciated.

[WPF binding declarative syntax: enable a GroupBox when a checkbox is NOT set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613182/wpf-binding-declarative-syntax-enable-a-groupbox-when-a-checkbox-is-not-set)

My Checkboxes are as follows:

```
<RadioButton Content="Recurring" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,12,0,0" Name="RecurringArchive" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Width="124" Checked="RecurringArchive_Checked"/>
<RadioButton Content="Run Once" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,12,0,0" Name="RunOnce" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="True" Width="77" Checked="RunOnce_Checked"/>
```

My GroupBox:

```
<GroupBox Header="Recurrence End Date" Height="72" Margin="12,267,12,0" Name="GrpRecurEndDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=RecurringArchive, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource DisableGroupBoxConverter}}"></GroupBox>
```

My Code for the Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
    public class DisableGroupBoxConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
    {       
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

                return !(bool)value;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }     
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it not easier to set it enabled when recurring is checked?

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned i'm using a customised version of the Telerik Scheduler control.

Comment: I think youre binding to the wrong RadioButton (atm youre binding to the RecurringArchive RadioButton, not the RunOnce RadioButton)